# Multi indices search with nested fields

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5, elasticsearch-2.0

I have two indices:

First, `questions`, have nested field `answers`. Second, `articles` do not have this field.

I try search by multi indices:

```
{
    "index": "questions, articles",
    "body":{
        "query":{
            "bool":{
                "must":{
                    "nested":{
                        "path": "answer",
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and get error `"query_parsing_exception: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [answer]"`

How I can search without errors, when one index have nested field, but another does not have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the [`indices` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-indices-query.html) and to use a different query for each index. Something like this:

```
GET /questions,articles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "indices": {
                  "indices": [
                    "questions"
                  ],
                  "query": {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "answer",
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "text": "bla"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_all": {}
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "some_common_field": {
              "value": "whatever"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```